# Invoking struct function gives "cannot refer to unexported field or method"

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I have a structure something like this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Id    string
}
```

and function:

```
func (m *MyStruct) id() {
   // doing something with id here
}
```

Also I have another structure like this:

```
type MyStruct2 struct {
    m *MyStruct
}
```

Now I have a function:

```
func foo(str *MyStruct2) {
    str.m.id()
}
```

But I'm getting error in compile time:

```
str.m.id undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method mypackage.(*MyStruct)."".id
```

How can I call this function correctly?

Answer (score 109):

From http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers:

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a **Unicode upper case letter** (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.

So basically only functions / variables starting with a capital letter would be usable outside the package.

Example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    id    string
}

func (m *MyStruct) Id() {
   // doing something with id here
}

//then

func foo(str *MyStruct2) {
    str.m.Id()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you change `MyStruct.Id` to `MyStruct.id`:

- You'll no longer be able to access it to initialize `MyStruct2`.
- `id` will be accessible only through its own package: *the `first` package*.
- Because: `MyStruct` and `MyStruct2` are in different packages.

---

**To solve the problem you can do this:**

Package `first`:

```
package first

type MyStruct struct {
    // `id` will be invisible outside of `first` package
    // because, it starts with a lowercase letter
    id string
}

// `Id()` is visible outside to `first` package 
// because, it starts with an uppercase letter
func (m *MyStruct) Id() string {
  return m.id
}

// Create a constructor function to return `*MyStruct`
func NewMyStruct(id string) *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{
        id: id,
    }
}
```

Package `second`:

```
package second

// Import MyStruct's package
import "first"

type MyStruct2 struct {
    // If you don't use `m` here as in your question, 
    // `first.MyStruct` will be promoted automatically.
    //
    // So, you can reach its methods directly, 
    // as if they're inside `MyStruct2`
    *first.MyStruct
}

// You can use `Id()` directly because it is promoted
// As if, inside `MyStruct2`
func foo(str *MyStruct2) {
    str.Id()
}

// You can initialize `MyStruct2` like this:
func run() {
    foo(&MyStruct2{
        MyStruct: first.NewMyStruct("3"),
    })
}
```