# Error in importing custom packages in Go Lang

Tags: go

I have created a library by the name `libfastget` which is in the `src` with my program as

```
src
|-libfastget
|  |-libfastget.go
|
|-MainProgram
   |-main.go
```

and the `libfastget` exports a funtion `fastget` as follows

```
package libfastget

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"

)


func fastget(urlPtr *string, nPtr *int, outFilePtr *string) download {
    .....
    return dl

}
```

When I use the library in my main program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "libfastget"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "flag"
    "time"

)
func uploadFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

         n:=libfastget.fastget(url,4,filename)

    }

}
```

I get the following error upon trying to build with `go build`

```
# FServe
./main.go:94: cannot refer to unexported name libfastget.fastget
./main.go:94: undefined: libfastget.fastget
```

The strange thing is that the library file libfastget.a is present in the pkg folder.

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487943/invoke-golang-struct-function-gives-cannot-refer-to-unexported-field-or-method . you must capitalize the function name to export it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

you would need to make your function exportable with an uppercase for its name:

```
func Fastget(...
```

Used as:

```
n:=libfastget.Fastget(url,4,filename)
```

The spec mentions: "[Exported identifiers](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)":

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "`Lu`"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the [package block](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) or it is a [field name](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) or [method name](http://golang.org/ref/spec#MethodName).
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

Comment: I just realized that the reffernce was pointing to my source code instead of the compiled library How can I fix that ??

Comment: @ShenalSilva once it compiles fully, your compiled library will be in sync with your source code.

Comment: define fully compiled ?? I compiled my library using go install libfastget

Comment: `cd libfastget` ; `go build`, then `cd MainProgram`; `go install`. You don't "install" your lib, only your main program: it will be statically linked with all its dependencies (including `libfastget`) and will generate one executable in `GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: what is the use of the libfastget.a file in the pkg directory if my main program does not build after i delete the source of the library package

Comment: @ShenalSilva you need the source of the library package in order to compile your main program. If those sources are *not* more recent than the `libfastget.a`, then they won't be recompiled. But you need those sources.

Comment: omg! "uppercase" ... remake all function kkk... good idea, Thanks VonC

Answer (score 3):

to export a function into another package the function identifier must start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started learning GO Lang (2 days back)
And what I found was you need to setup a [workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) folder to make the local packages import into other projects or main.go files. I'm using VS Code editor. Please correct me if Im wrong, but this setup works fine for me.

Inside your `bash_profile` OR `.zshrc` file add below lines, update the GOPATH as per your folder path.

```
export GOPATH=~/projects/GO_PROJECTS
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

[image]

and this is my `sayHello.go` file, please note to be able to export a function the `func` name should start with a CapitalCase **SayHello**

```
package utils

import "fmt"

func SayHello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, Ajinkya")
}
```

and now I am able to import utils package into main.go file

```
package main

import (
    "go_proj1/utils"
)

func main() {
    utils.SayHello()
}
```

Comment: Its not standard procedure to name package as *utils* according to [GO_Doc](https://blog.golang.org/package-names#TOC_5).

Answer (score -1):

1. set the current directory as GOPATH
2. or you can use local import as follows

> move your main.go to the ../ directory to the libfastget.go.
>   i mean the files looks like:
>   src
>   |-libfastget
>   |  |-libfastget.go
>   |
>   |-main.go  
>   
>   import "./libfastget"