# cannot refer to unexported name m.β

Tags: unicode, go, package

Have a look at these two simple packages:

```
package m
const β = 1
```

```
package main
import ("m";"fmt")
func main() {
    fmt.Println(m.β)
}
```

I get this error when I try to compile them:

```
$ GOPATH=`pwd` go run a.go 
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:4: cannot refer to unexported name m.β
./a.go:4: undefined: m.β
```

Why? I tried replacing the β with B in both packages, and it works, but I'm trying to use the proper symbol here. Maybe both packages are using homoglyphs or different encodings for some reason?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The go specifications say that an identifier is exported if

> the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>   letter (Unicode class "Lu")

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(unicode.IsUpper('β'))
}
```

returns

```
false
```

http://play.golang.org/p/6KxF5-Cq8P

Answer (score 3):

β is lowercase, so it is not exported and can't be used from outside that package.

```
fmt.Println(unicode.IsLower('β'))
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/kmv8LyDLkM)

Answer (score 1):

A function , method in an exported package needs to start with an upper case letter. Ran into the same problem yesterday [Error in importing custom packages in Go Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501875/error-in-importing-custom-packages-in-go-lang)

Comment: looks uppercase to me

Comment: @Dog it's not though, if you think it's a bug you should report it.

Comment: Just opened a thread on the golang-nuts mailing list. Apparently β is a lower case letter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta

Comment: nuts indeed, only allowing uppercase identifiers ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first character of an exported identifier's name must be a Unicode upper case letter. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

const Β = 1

func main() {
    const (
        GreekLowerβ = 'β'
        GreekUpperΒ = 'Β'
    )
    fmt.Println(GreekLowerβ, unicode.IsUpper(GreekLowerβ))
    fmt.Println(GreekUpperΒ, unicode.IsUpper(GreekUpperΒ))
}
```

Output:

```
946 false
914 true
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Exported identifiers](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

---

[Greek alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet): Β β  beta