# sqlx - non-struct dest type struct with >1 columns (2)

Tags: go, sqlx

I have searched the error and I have find two questions:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487943/invoke-golang-struct-function-gives-cannot-refer-to-unexported-field-or-method), but my question is not duplicate  of it
- [And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710974/non-struct-dest-type-struct-with-1-columns), but there is no answer in this question.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var schema = `
CREATE TABLE films (
  code int,
  name VARCHAR(10)
)`

type Film struct {
    code int
    name string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", "user=demas password=root host=192.168.99.100 port=32768 dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    db.MustExec(schema)

    tx := db.MustBegin()
    tx.MustExec("INSERT INTO films(code, name) VALUES($1, $2)", 10, "one")
    tx.MustExec("INSERT INTO films(code, name) VALUES($1, $2)", 20, "two")
    tx.Commit()

    films := []Film{}
    err = db.Select(&films, "SELECT * FROM public.films")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

It creates table and insert 2 records, but can not return them back:

```
λ go run main.go
2016/09/26 14:46:04 non-struct dest type struct with >1 columns (2)
exit status 1
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It works if you export your fields:

```
type Film struct {
    Code int
    Name string
}
```

Notice the uppercase (`Code`, not `code`).