# Return value of struct in function and use it in another package

Tags: go, struct

I try create package config in my example project but something doesn't work as I expected, I have folder structure:

```
config/config.go // package config
main.go  // package main
```

and I want use config in my main file:

```
func main() {
    conf := config.GetConf()

    db := dbConn{
        schemas:  map[string]*sql.DB{},
        url:      fmt.Sprintf("tcp(%s)", conf.db['dev']),
        username: db.user,
        password: db.password,
    }
    db.create()
}
```

my config file:

```
type Config struct {
    db         map[string]string
    user     string
    password string
}

func GetConf() *Config {
    config := Config{
        db: map[string]string{
            "dev": "database.url",
        },
        user: "root",
        password: "pass",
    }

    return &config
}
```

compiler return error: conf.db undefined (cannot refer to unexported field or method db)

Comment: This is covered on page 3 of the "basics" section of the Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke golang struct function gives "cannot refer to unexported field or method"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487943/invoke-golang-struct-function-gives-cannot-refer-to-unexported-field-or-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a compile-time error to refer to unexported identifiers from other packages (other than the declaring package).

Export the identifiers (start them with an uppercase letter), and it will work.

```
type Config struct {
    DB       map[string]string
    User     string
    Password string
}

func GetConf() *Config {
    config := Config{
        DB: map[string]string{
            "dev": "database.url",
        },
        User:     "root",
        Password: "pass",
    }

    return &config
}
```

And in your main:

```
func main() {
    conf := config.GetConf()

    db := dbConn{
        schemas:  map[string]*sql.DB{},
        url:      fmt.Sprintf("tcp(%s)", conf.DB['dev']),
        username: conf.User,
        password: conf.Password,
    }
    db.create()
}
```